# Implement Digest authentication via HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, digest

Does anyone know how to screen scrape web-sites that use digest http authentication?
I use code like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SiteUrl);
request.Credentials=new NetworkCredential(Login, Password)
```

I'm able to access the site's mainpage, but when I try to surf to any other pages (using another request with the same credentials) I get "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" error.

I used Fiddler to compare requests of my C# application with Mozilla Firefox requests.

2 URLs that I try to access are:
https://mysiteurl/forum/index.php
https://mysiteurl/forum/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=d104363e563968b4e4c07e04f4a15203

Here are 2 requests () of my C# app:

```
Authorization: Digest username="xxx",realm="abc",nonce="NXa26+NjBAA=747dfd1776c9d585bd388377ef3160f1ff265429",uri="/forum/index.php",algorithm="MD5",cnonce="89179bf17dd27785aa1c88ad976817c9",nc=00000001,qop="auth",response="3088821620d9cbbf71e775fddbacfb6d"

Authorization: Digest username="xxx",realm="abc",nonce="1h7T6+NjBAA=4fed4d804d0edcb54bf4c2f912246330d96afa76",uri="/forum/viewforum.php",algorithm="MD5",cnonce="bb990b0516a371549401c0289fbacc7c",nc=00000001,qop="auth",response="1ddb95a45fd7ea8dbefd37a2db705e3a"
```

And that's what Firefox sending to the server:

```
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="abc", nonce="T9ICNeRjBAA=4fbb28d42db044e182116ac27176e81d067a313c", uri="/forum/", algorithm=MD5, response="33f29dcc5d70b61be18eaddfca9bd601", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="ab96bbe39d8d776d"
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="abc", nonce="T9ICNeRjBAA=4fbb28d42db044e182116ac27176e81d067a313c", uri="/forum/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=d104363e563968b4e4c07e04f4a15203", algorithm=MD5, response="a996dae9368a79d49f2f29ea7a327cd5", qop=auth, nc=00000002, cnonce="e233ae90908860e1"
```

So in my app I have different values in "nonce" field while in Firefox this field is the same. On the other hand I have same values in "nc" field while Firefox increments this field.

Also when my app tries to access site pages in Fiddler i can see that it always gets response "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required", while Firefox authorizes only once. I've tried to set request.PreAuthenticate = true; but it seems to have no effect...

My question is: how to properly implement digest authentication using C#? Are there any standard methods or do I have to do it from scratch? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Create a class Digest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace NUI
{
    public class DigestAuthFixer
    {
        private static string _host;
        private static string _user;
        private static string _password;
        private static string _realm;
        private static string _nonce;
        private static string _qop;
        private static string _cnonce;
        private static DateTime _cnonceDate;
        private static int _nc;

        public DigestAuthFixer(string host, string user, string password)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            _host = host;
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
        }

        private string CalculateMd5Hash(
            string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in hash)
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string GrabHeaderVar(
            string varName,
            string header)
        {
            var regHeader = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}=""([^""]*)""", varName));
            var matchHeader = regHeader.Match(header);
            if (matchHeader.Success)
                return matchHeader.Groups[1].Value;
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Header {0} not found", varName));
        }

        private string GetDigestHeader(
            string dir)
        {
            _nc = _nc + 1;

            var ha1 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", _user, _realm, _password));
            var ha2 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "GET", dir));
            var digestResponse =
                CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2:00000000}:{3}:{4}:{5}", ha1, _nonce, _nc, _cnonce, _qop, ha2));

            return string.Format("Digest username=\"{0}\", realm=\"{1}\", nonce=\"{2}\", uri=\"{3}\", " +
                "algorithm=MD5, response=\"{4}\", qop={5}, nc={6:00000000}, cnonce=\"{7}\"",
                _user, _realm, _nonce, dir, digestResponse, _qop, _nc, _cnonce);
        }

        public string GrabResponse(
            string dir)
        {
            var url = _host + dir;
            var uri = new Uri(url);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

            // If we've got a recent Auth header, re-use it!
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cnonce) &&
                DateTime.Now.Subtract(_cnonceDate).TotalHours < 1.0)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDigestHeader(dir));
            }

            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Try to fix a 401 exception by adding a Authorization header
                if (ex.Response == null || ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    throw;

                var wwwAuthenticateHeader = ex.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
                _realm = GrabHeaderVar("realm", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _nonce = GrabHeaderVar("nonce", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _qop = GrabHeaderVar("qop", wwwAuthenticateHeader);

                _nc = 0;
                _cnonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
                _cnonceDate = DateTime.Now;

                var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request2.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDigestHeader(dir));
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
            }
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your application, you can use the following code:

```
DigestAuthFixer digest = new DigestAuthFixer(url, username, password);
string strReturn = digest.GrabResponse(url);
```

Comment: +1 Just used this to connect to my router, but it returns a Set-Cookie header, so you need to add the cookies to all subsequent requests if you happen upon same situation.
p.s. to parse cookies you can use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1055883/289992

Comment: I know this is an ancient post, but if anyone like me stumbles over this problem and would like to use kitwalkers solution, be advised that the usage example above is incorrect.
The DigestAuthFixer constructor and the GrabResponse method should not have the full URL as first parameter.
Instead constructor should only have the host part, and GrabResponse only the rest of the URL (without host).

Comment: It doesn't work for me even with that change. I get 401 no matter what I try. PostMan does not on same URL with same username and Password. I also generates a different Auth Digest Auth String.
Anyone using a modified version of this that works? Trying to use algorythm 'MD5-sess' which works for PostMan. Trying to replicate PostMan.

Comment: A small fix: GrabResponse parameter must be url path, contructor url must be base url. `DigestAuthFixer digest = new DigestAuthFixer(baseUrl, username, password);
string strReturn = digest.GrabResponse(urlPath);` Like: `DigestAuthFixer digest = new DigestAuthFixer("http://localhost:8080/", username, password);
string strReturn = digest.GrabResponse("GetSomething/Index");`

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently observing the same issue, though the web server I'm testing this against is my own. The server logs show:

```
Digest: uri mismatch - </var/path/some.jpg> does not match request-uri
        </var/path/some.jpg?parameter=123456789>
```

I tried removing the arguments from the URL (as that seemed to be what's different), but the error still occurred just like before.

My conclusion is that the URL arguments have to be included in the digest hash as well and that the `HttpWebRequest` is for some reason removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the good work of @kitwalker, here's a delegating handler I wrote for DotNetCore 3.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Respond to a Digest auth challenge and retry the request.
    /// See <c>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication</c>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// Example response header with challenge details:
    /// header: www-authenticate
    /// value: <c>Digest realm="Signaling Controller", charset="UTF-8", algorithm=MD5, nonce="6088c71a:a699df7b2e03c53cfe06f8d070f4345c", qop="auth"</c>
    /// </example>
    public class DigestAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly CredentialSettings _settings;

        public DigestAuthenticationHandler(ILogger<DigestAuthenticationHandler> logger, CredentialSettings settings)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var username = _settings?.Username;
            var password = _settings?.Password;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username), "Missing credentials.");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password), "Missing credentials.");
            }

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                var header = response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate;
                var value = header.FirstOrDefault();

                _logger.LogDebug("Challenged with scheme: '{Scheme}'", value?.Scheme ?? "(unknown)");

                if (string.Compare(value?.Scheme, "Digest", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Authentication challenge is not of type 'Digest' - give up");
                    return response;
                }

                var details = new DigestAuthenticationDetails(value?.Parameter);

                _logger.LogDebug("Authentication challenge details: {Details}", details);

                var qop = details["qop"];
                var realm = details["realm"];
                var nonce = details["nonce"];
                var algorithm = details["algorithm"];

                if (algorithm != "MD5")
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Algorithm '{Algorithm}' unsupported; cannot respond to Digest auth challenge - give up", algorithm);
                    return response;
                }

                var cnonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
                var nc = 1;

                var uri = request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;

                var digest = BuildDigestHeader(username, password, request.Method, uri, realm, algorithm, nonce, cnonce, qop, nc);

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", digest);

                var retry = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

                return retry;
            }

            return response;
        }

        private static string BuildDigestHeader(
            string username,
            string password,
            HttpMethod method,
            string uri,
            string realm,
            string algorithm,
            string nonce,
            string cnonce,
            string qop,
            int nc)
        {
            static string CalculateMd5Hash(string input)
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
                var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var b in hash)
                {
                    builder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
                }

                return builder.ToString();
            }

            var ha1 = CalculateMd5Hash($"{username}:{realm}:{password}");
            var ha2 = CalculateMd5Hash($"{method}:{uri}");
            var digestResponse = CalculateMd5Hash($"{ha1}:{nonce}:{nc:00000000}:{cnonce}:{qop}:{ha2}");

            return "Digest "
                   + $"username=\"{username}\", "
                   + $"realm=\"{realm}\", "
                   + $"nonce=\"{nonce}\", "
                   + $"uri=\"{uri}\", "
                   + $"algorithm=\"{algorithm}\", "
                   + $"response=\"{digestResponse}\", "
                   + $"qop={qop}, "
                   + $"nc={nc:00000000}, "
                   + $"cnonce=\"{cnonce}\"";
        }

        private class DigestAuthenticationDetails
        {
            private readonly Dictionary<string, string?> _values;

            public DigestAuthenticationDetails(string? authentication)
            {
                _values = new Dictionary<string, string?>();

                if (authentication != null)
                {
                    foreach (var pair in authentication.Split(","))
                    {
                        var item = pair.Split("=");

                        string? key = null;
                        string? value = null;

                        if (item.Length == 1)
                        {
                            key = item.ElementAt(0);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            key = item.ElementAt(0);
                            value = item.ElementAt(1);
                        }

                        key = key
                            .Trim()
                            .Replace("\"", "")
                            .Replace("'", "")
                            .ToLower();

                        value = value
                            ?.Trim()
                            .Replace("\"", "")
                            .Replace("'", "");

                        _values.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            public string this[string key] => GetValueOrThrow(key);

            public override string ToString()
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var (key, value) in _values)
                {
                    builder.Append($"'{key}'='{value}' ");
                }

                return builder.ToString();
            }

            private string GetValueOrThrow(string key)
            {
                if (_values.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
                {
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        return value;
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value), $"No value for key '{key}'.");
                }

                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), $"Key '{key}' was not found in Digest auth challenge.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then wherever you register services, add the delegating handler to the `HttpClient` that needs digest auth capability:

```
services.AddTransient<DigestAuthenticationHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<ServiceThatNeedsHttpClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<DigestAuthenticationHandler>();
```

Note: No support for caching the previous digest header used.