# HttpWebResponse.Cookies empty despite Set-Cookie Header (no-redirect)

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm struggling to figure out what is wrong here.  I'm sending login information, I can see the Set-Cookie in the Header with the correct value, but the Cookies collection is not getting filled.

This is HTTPS, the login auto-redirects, but I disabled it with AllowAutoRedirect=false to try to troubleshoot this issue.

In this screenshot, you can easily see the debug information and that the cookie should be getting set.  I am setting my httpWebRequest.Cookie to a new CookieCollection.

[image: Right click and select view image to see full-size.]

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
CookieContainer reqCookies = new CookieContainer();
string url = "https://example.com";
string[] email = user.Split('@');
email[0] = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email[0]);
user = email[0] + "@" + email[1];
pass = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pass);

string postData = "email=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.Referer = url;
httpRequest.CookieContainer = reqCookies;
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1003.1 Safari/535.19";
httpRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
using (Stream postStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    postStream.Close();
}

httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse b = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Tried the exact same code connecting to http://www.yahoo.com and the cookies are put into my collection...  Argh...

Here is the Set-Cookie Header value:

> s=541E2101-B768-45C8-B814-34A00525E50F; Domain=example.com; Path=/;
>   Version=1

Comment: You sure you have correct domain name set from server? is it domain.com or .domain.com , they both are different. Can you post your ASP.NET your code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE** five years later, someone actually mentioned the correct way to do it: setting up the CookieContainer correctly in the first place and letting it handle everything. Please refer to Sam's solution further down.

I've found that issue as well, when reading Cookies in C# that were created by a C# ASP.NET app... ;)

Not sure if it has to do with it, but I found that the two Cookies that are set in my case are written in a single Set-Cookie header, with the cookie payload separated by commas. So I adapted AppDeveloper's solution to deal with this multiple-cookie issue, as well as fixing the name/value thing I mentioned in the comments.

```
private static void fixCookies(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
    {
        string name = response.Headers.GetKey(i);
        if (name != "Set-Cookie")
            continue;
        string value = response.Headers.Get(i);
        foreach (var singleCookie in value.Split(','))
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(singleCookie, "(.+?)=(.+?);");
            if (match.Captures.Count == 0)
                continue;
            response.Cookies.Add(
                new Cookie(
                    match.Groups[1].ToString(), 
                    match.Groups[2].ToString(), 
                    "/", 
                    request.Host.Split(':')[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quick fix  " coki1=val1; expires=sat,monday 2017 ; domain:asdf.com ,  coki2=val2; expires=sat,monday 2017 ; domain:asdf.com , ".   comma is used in expires date too. su it messes up  split(",")         add this for temporary fix               value =  Regex.Replace(value , "(e|E)xpires=(.+?)(;|$)|(P|p)ath=(.+?);", "");

Comment: as @blackholeearth0_gmail mentioned, splitting from comma will produce extra incorrect cookies as there is a comma in `expires` header `Wed, 04-Apr-18`

Comment: @Sam's answer is much more elegant.

Comment: @TimWilson you are absolutely right. updating answer to refer to that solution.

Comment: Thank you! I almost went down the parsing route until I found Sam's answer. I wanted to make sure any other poor soul who has to deal with cookies in C# knows how to do it properly.

My use case was writing an automated test against APIs that use forms authentication.

Answer (score 18):

The `Cookies` property will be null unless the `CookieContainer` is set on the `HttpWebRequest`. So the proper way to do this is to set the `CookieContainer` member before retrieving the response:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(..);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

var response = request.GetResponse();
// ..response.Cookies will now contain the cookies sent back by the server.
```

You don't need to manually parse `Set-Cookie`.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) for more information.

Answer (score 15):

It seems like `Set-Cookie` header sent by the website is malformed (Not in the typical format it should have been).

In such case you need to Parse cookie manually and it it to the `CookieContainer`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.Headers.Count; i++)
{
    string name = b.Headers.GetKey(i);
    string value = b.Headers.Get(i);
    if (name == "Set-Cookie")
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(value, "(.+?)=(.+?);");
        if (match.Captures.Count > 0)
        {
            reqCookies.Add(new Cookie(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value, "/", "example.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is a custom object and I had to modify and simplify it for posting here.  Sorry for leaving out a line, I fixed it immediately.

Comment: Look at the screenshot please.  b.Cookies isn't null but it has no Cookies in it.  Count = 0 and enumeration yielded no results.

Comment: This works, after I fixed the reqCookies.Add to parse the match instead of trying to use the header name and values.  I find it hard to believe the cookie is malformed as it works fine in every browser I've tried.  Here's the Set-Cookie value that it may think is malformed: "s=541E2101-B768-45C8-B814-34A00525E50F; Domain=example.com; Path=/; Version=1"  I'd really like to fully understand what is wrong as this solution is just a work-around.

Comment: @Brad - something `Set-Cookie` header is not in the exact format that CookieParser is built with!

Comment: Thanks for this. In the `reqCookies.Add` line however, you're not adding the Cookie name, but the head name, which is "Set-Cookie"
I believe what you want to write there is `httpResponse.Cookies.Add(new Cookie(match.Groups[1].ToString(), match.Groups[2].ToString(), "/", host));`

Comment: @Nicolas78 - httpResponse.Cookies is cookie collection, nt the container, + the container need the cookie to be send to next sequential request, so the cookie was added to the reqCookie (CookieContainer)

Comment: Ah yes that's true. But that's kinda independent of the fact that you're adding a cookie called "Set-Cookie", no?

Comment: This code adds only one cookie to the cookie collection. With multiple cookies the snippet from Nicolas78 works.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `CookieContainer` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055883/2675154).
What tripped these regex approaches up for me was a comma in `expires=Tue, ...`.

Answer (score 5):

Looking on other answers I improved incorrect cookie handling. Unlike those answers this one automatically handles all cookie properties (such as expired, secure, etc.) and works with all range of cookies (even when there are more than 1 incorrect cookie).

It's implemented as extension method and can be used in the following way:

```
//...
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                request.FixCookies(response);
//...
```

`FixCookies()` extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace AG.WebHelpers
{
    static public class ExtensionMethods
    {
        static public void FixCookies(this HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                string name = response.Headers.GetKey(i);
                if (name != "Set-Cookie")
                    continue;
                string value = response.Headers.Get(i);
                var cookieCollection = ParseCookieString(value, () => request.Host.Split(':')[0]);
                response.Cookies.Add(cookieCollection);
            }
        }

        static private CookieCollection ParseCookieString(string cookieString, Func<string> getCookieDomainIfItIsMissingInCookie)
        {
            bool secure = false;
            bool httpOnly = false;

            string domainFromCookie = null;
            string path = null;
            string expiresString = null;

            Dictionary<string, string> cookiesValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var cookieValuePairsStrings = cookieString.Split(';');
            foreach(string cookieValuePairString in cookieValuePairsStrings)
            {
                var pairArr = cookieValuePairString.Split('=');
                int pairArrLength = pairArr.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < pairArrLength; i++)
                {
                    pairArr[i] = pairArr[i].Trim();
                }
                string propertyName = pairArr[0];
                if (pairArrLength == 1)
                {
                    if (propertyName.Equals("httponly", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        httpOnly = true;
                    else if (propertyName.Equals("secure", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        secure = true;
                    else
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unknown cookie property \"{0}\". All cookie is \"{1}\"", propertyName, cookieString));
                    continue;
                }

                string propertyValue = pairArr[1];
                if (propertyName.Equals("expires", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    expiresString = propertyValue;
                else if (propertyName.Equals("domain", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    domainFromCookie = propertyValue;
                else if (propertyName.Equals("path", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    path = propertyValue;
                else
                    cookiesValues.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
            }

            DateTime expiresDateTime;
            if (expiresString != null)
            {
                expiresDateTime = DateTime.Parse(expiresString);
            }
            else
            {
                expiresDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainFromCookie))
            {
                domainFromCookie = getCookieDomainIfItIsMissingInCookie();
            }

            CookieCollection cookieCollection = new CookieCollection();
            foreach (var pair in cookiesValues)
            {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(pair.Key, pair.Value, path, domainFromCookie);
                cookie.Secure = secure;
                cookie.HttpOnly = httpOnly;
                cookie.Expires = expiresDateTime;

                cookieCollection.Add(cookie);
            }
            return cookieCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are splitting the cookie value on '=' - this is a potential pitfall if the value is a base64 encoded string

Answer (score 2):

That could be a bit late, but you can use function SetCookies

```
var cHeader = responce.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
var cookie = new CookieContainer();
cookie.SetCookies(new Uri("[...]"), cHeader);
```

Comment: This will fail if `set-cookie` contains `path=/`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but I came across some code that properly parses a "Set-Cookie" header. It handles cookies separated by commas and extracts the name, expiration, path, value, and domain of each cookie.

This code works better than Microsoft's own cookie parser and this is really what the official cookie parser should be doing. I don't have any clue why Microsoft hasn't fixed this yet since it's a very common issue.

Here is the original code:
http://snipplr.com/view/4427/

I'm posting it here in case the link goes down at some point:

```
public static CookieCollection GetAllCookiesFromHeader(string strHeader, string strHost)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();
    if (strHeader != string.Empty)
    {
        al = ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(strHeader);
        cc = ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(al, strHost);
    }
    return cc;
}


private static ArrayList ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(string strCookHeader)
{
    strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\r", "");
    strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\n", "");
    string[] strCookTemp = strCookHeader.Split(',');
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    int n = strCookTemp.Length;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (strCookTemp[i].IndexOf("expires=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            al.Add(strCookTemp[i] + "," + strCookTemp[i + 1]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            al.Add(strCookTemp[i]);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return al;
}


private static CookieCollection ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(ArrayList al, string strHost)
{
    CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();

    int alcount = al.Count;
    string strEachCook;
    string[] strEachCookParts;
    for (int i = 0; i < alcount; i++)
    {
        strEachCook = al[i].ToString();
        strEachCookParts = strEachCook.Split(';');
        int intEachCookPartsCount = strEachCookParts.Length;
        string strCNameAndCValue = string.Empty;
        string strPNameAndPValue = string.Empty;
        string strDNameAndDValue = string.Empty;
        string[] NameValuePairTemp;
        Cookie cookTemp = new Cookie();

        for (int j = 0; j < intEachCookPartsCount; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                strCNameAndCValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strCNameAndCValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    int firstEqual = strCNameAndCValue.IndexOf("=");
                    string firstName = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(0, firstEqual);
                    string allValue = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(firstEqual + 1, strCNameAndCValue.Length - (firstEqual + 1));
                    cookTemp.Name = firstName;
                    cookTemp.Value = allValue;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("path", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                strPNameAndPValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strPNameAndPValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    NameValuePairTemp = strPNameAndPValue.Split('=');
                    if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        cookTemp.Path = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookTemp.Path = "/";
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("domain", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                strPNameAndPValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strPNameAndPValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    NameValuePairTemp = strPNameAndPValue.Split('=');

                    if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        cookTemp.Domain = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (cookTemp.Path == string.Empty)
        {
            cookTemp.Path = "/";
        }
        if (cookTemp.Domain == string.Empty)
        {
            cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
        }
        cc.Add(cookTemp);
    }
    return cc;
}
```