# IIS digest authentication, hash algorithm

Tags: iis-7.5, digest-authentication

I am trying to implement my own service side authentication component for WebApi that can perform matching for hashed username/password sent by webclient described at [How can I do digest authentication with HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172510/how-can-i-do-digest-authentication-with-httpwebrequest)

This article  (http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/digest-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-part-1/) suggests that the IIS Digest Authentication uses MD5 for hashing.

Are there any official IIS docs that confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes their are offical documents that describe it as using MD5

"Digest authentication transmits credentials across the network as an MD5 hash"
-  [Microsoft Docs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/809552a3-3473-48a7-9683-c6df0cdfda21.mspx?mfr=true)