# How to use WebClient.DownloadFile with digest authentication and a query string

Tags: c#, .net, apache, webclient, digest-authentication

How do I use `WebClient.DownloadFile` with digest authentication and a query string?

When I try to use it I get a 401 response.

This is the Apache error log:

```
[Tue Jun 24 17:31:49 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Digest: uri mismatch - </file-1.php> does not match request-uri </file-1.php?since=1403587422>
```

Here is how I try to download the file:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/file-1.php?since=1403587422");
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(
  new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)),
  "Digest",
  new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
);
webClient.Credentials = credentialCache;
webClient.DownloadFile(uri, file.OutputFile);
```

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172510/how-can-i-do-digest-authentication-with-httpwebrequest

Comment: You are supposed to get a 401 response after the request. The 401 response contains the WWW-Authenticate header that you need to calculate the challenge response. Check out how the digest authentication protocol works. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @MikeHixson I get the 401 fine, its the request after that which fails.

Comment: Try the workaround in the below link <https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571052/digest-authentication-does-not-send-the-full-uri-path-in-the-uri-parameter>

Comment: just for debug purpose hard-code the url on the credentialCache "http : //example.com" and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Petah Maybe this will help? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_digest.html Try adding this to your httpd.conf
BrowserMatch "MSIE" AuthDigestEnableQueryStringHack=On

Comment: @Petah This is where I found it originally:  https://www.drupal.org/node/128962

Answer (score 2):

```
WebClient webCl = new WebClient();
webCl.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "Password");
webCl.DownloadFile(file download URL, fil save path with FileName);
```