# Digest auth not return XML results XML in c#

Tags: c#, python, webrequest

I'm trying to convert a Python script to C# but have hit a problem.

The python script uses HTTPDigestAuth to authrenticate the for the API

```
r = requests.get(apiUrl,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(apiuser, apipass))
```

I've tried the following in C# but it clearly not authenticating correctly as when I look at the headers after the call its showing as DENY, yet the exact same credentials in Python work perfectly.

Here is the code I'm trying below.

```
string url = "www.test.com";

string UserName = "xx";
string Password = "L12312321312";

NetworkCredential wrCred = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myWebRequest.Credentials = wrCred;
myWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

//Get Reponse
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

//Data stream
Stream dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.  
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

//Check
MessageBox.Show(myWebResponse.Headers.ToString());

reader.Close();
myWebResponse.Close();
```

is there something I'm missing as the header results are the same as if I alter the python script to use basic auth instead (like below) so its like its not using Digest Auth and just defaulting to Basic.

```
r = requests.get(apiUrl,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(apiuser, apipass))
```

If I return the status code for the webresponse it returning OK but no body or content is returned again which makes me think its not using Digest Auth.

Comment: Where are you setting credentials for WebRequest?

Comment: Sorry I've onl just spotted that error and added the
<br><br/>

myWebRequest.Credentials = wrCred;
<br><br/>

Comment: Could you share the entire WebRequest call? Do you have,
WebResponse response = myWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Yes I've added it above

Comment: To use Digest Authentication, can you try providing CredentialCache as following,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172510/how-can-i-do-digest-authentication-with-httpwebrequest

Comment: I've already tried that I'm afraid with no luck, This just seems poor that this is not a simple task like in Python I might just stick with the Python version seems far better.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that mate, one last try, did you try above without setting PreAuthenticate.

Comment: Sorry still no luck, thanks for your help however but I think C# will be ditched for this task.